# Failed to resolve after bintray upload and jcenter link

Tags: gradle, bintray, jcenter

I uploaded a library to bintray and got approved for it to be linked with jcenter() but when I try to include the dependency:

```
compile 'com.dinomitesoft.owlorbit.owlorbitsdk:owlorbit-sdk:1.0.0'
```

It says "Failed to resolve".. Here is what my repositories looks like currently:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

If I include the bintray repository it's able to compile fine e.g.:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/owlorbit-llc/Owlorbit/'
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to setup a Sonatype account?

Here's the link to the bintray project:
https://bintray.com/owlorbit-llc/Owlorbit/Owlorbit_SDK

It says it's linked to JCenter:

[image]

Comment: It is in bintray but it is not synced with jcenter. Check http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/dinomitesoft/owlorbit/owlorbitsdk If you are the owner of the library there is an "Add to Jcenter" button on Bintray

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i have it linked with jcenter though.  And it got approved.  Or is there another button..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bintray resolved the issue after I sent them a support ticket!

Comment: I am still getting the same issue. I linked my bintray library repo to jcenter by clicking "add to jcenter" button. I also got message saying "Your request to include your package <package> in Bintray's JCenter has been approved."  But still it shows failed to resolve error (in case of jecnter) and it compiles if I add my bintray repo url in gradle.

Comment: @TechHelper please check the bintray-name, artifact id and package name and if it is not unique, please provide same name and check, bintray support team gave me this key

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the help. Now I have published my 2 libraries on Github (https://github.com/TechHelper/) and bintray (jcenter) successfully. The issue was related to proper declaration of bintray credentials.